# C++ error:invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const wchar_t* because of swprintf

Tags: c++

[the file I want to compile](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/CommandLineFPS/blob/master/CommandLineFPS.cpp)

first error:

> cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}|

I fixed it by changing `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` to `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW`.

However I get another error on this line:

```
swprintf(screen, 40, L"X=%3.2f, Y=%3.2f, A=%3.2f FPS=%3.2f ", fPlayerX, fPlayerY, fPlayerA, 1.0f/fElapsedTime);
```

> invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const wchar_t*' [-fpermissive]|
>   initializing argument 2 of 'int swprintf(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, ...)'|

How can I compile this code?

Comment: Wait a second ... maybe you simply need to compile with `UNICODE` defined? (or is it `_UNICODE`, I can't remember)

Answer (score 1):

The `swprintf` function you're using does not appear to take a buffer size. You may want to consider using [`_snwprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l?view=vs-2019) instead.

```
_snwprintf(screen, 40, L"X=%3.2f, Y=%3.2f, A=%3.2f FPS=%3.2f ", fPlayerX, fPlayerY, fPlayerA, 1.0f/fElapsedTime);
```

You may get warned that this function is unsafe - the suggested alternative is [`_snwprintf_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-s-snprintf-s-l-snwprintf-s-snwprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019) where you must specify both the size of the buffer **and** the maximum number of characters to write. In practice, these are often the same, so most of the time, calls to this function look like this:

```
_snwprintf_s(screen, 40, 40, L"X=%3.2f, Y=%3.2f, A=%3.2f FPS=%3.2f ", fPlayerX, fPlayerY, fPlayerA, 1.0f/fElapsedTime);
```

Comment: The second argument does indeed seem to be a max out size, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf

Comment: Indeed, it normally does, but the error message provided would indicate that the version of `swprintf` that they are using does not.

Comment: thank you very much. it is work. I appreciate for your help